# How to develop two list views that lead to one detail view in django?

Tags: python, django, listview, orm, django-3.0

I want to create a website that has a section for events.
So the mapping would be done as:

Homepage > Events > Event name > Event date > Event details

Basically, the same type of event was held multiple times a year, so event date is a list of dates on which the event was held.

I don't know how to approach this problem. I mean, I want to display a list that further displays another list and then the event details are displayed.

I don't have any clue on how to do that in django.

Comment: You should try to improve a bit your question. have you tried something? Do you have a working version of a minimal web (at least runnning Django's server)? If you have those things, what it looks that you want to do is create a view which is a ListView for the Events, and the item in the list (events) would link to a DetailView.

Comment: I can do this with listview Home > Events > Event list > EventDetail. I don't know how to add another list to filter out things

Comment: I have a server running already, this is a new feature

Comment: What does "I can do this with listview Home > Events > Event list > EventDetail." mean? That you already have created those views?